# What is this tensor operation called?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I'm wondering if the following operation has a name:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    \end{pmatrix} ? M = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    aM & bM & cM \\
    dM & eM & fM \\
    gM & hM & iM \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

In other words the operation multiplies each element of $n$ rank tensor $N$ as scalars by the whole second $m$ rank tensor $M$, creating a $n+m$ rank tensor.

(I need to perform it in a program I am writing. Before I implement it myself, I would like to check if it already exists in the libraries I am using. The problem is I don't have a clue what to search for. And the operation seems rather elementary, so it likely exists.)

Edit: I edited the question to make it less confusing and use proper nomenclature.

Comment: Matrix dimensions are usually specified using two positive integers, e.g. $n \times m$ matrix. It's unclear what an $n$-dimensional matrix $N$ means. Are you talking about square matrices?

Assuming you are, this is like scalar multiplication of matrices combined with matrix concatenation in some way. I'm sure most libraries have matrix concatenation operations, just look up the docs to figure out exactly how to specify it.

Comment: It seems to me that you're conceptualizing the concept of a rank-2 tensor as a "2-dimensional matrix." A matrix, by definition, is a 2-d grid of elements. A tensor generalizes this concept (e.g. rank-1 tensor = vector)

Comment: Yes, I've corrected the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Wait, it's just a tensor product. Now i feel like a total idiot.

Comment: If it is a tensor product that you're after, feel free to write it as an answer to your own question. It may help somebody in the future who looks this up. And don't feel like an idiot, this happens all the time to all of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This operation is called Kronecker Product. Here is the Wikipedia's link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Kronecker%20product,resulting%20in%20a%20block%20matrix.&text=The%20Kronecker%20product%20is%20named,to%20define%20and%20use%20it.

Comment: Note from question author: This is correct answer to the initial question (when I was mistakenly talking about matrices instead of tensors). Also Kronecker Product is a special case of the tensor product which I was (partially) after.

Comment: The only potential problem with tensor product is that it doesn't separate the result into dimensions as I desired, but all the elements are in the right places to easily reshape the result without any need for memory reallocation. (It might not be mathematically exactly what I ask for after edition, but it does the trick from the programming side.)

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @Nitin Tomar, it is a **Kronecker product**, and your $?$ point has to be replaced by the classical symbol $\otimes$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    \end{pmatrix} \otimes M = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    aM & bM & cM \\
    dM & eM & fM \\
    gM & hM & iM \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Kronecker product has many nice properties, for example regarding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but not in general commutativity.

As you address programming languages, Matlab for example has a special function called "kron" for this operation :

```
 L=[a,b,c
    d,e,f
    g,h,i];
 M=[j,k
    l,m];
 kron(L,M)
```

Related : you can also define a Kronecker $\oplus$ operation.

Comment: Not exactly: the Kronecker product of two matrices gives a matrix; the operation OP defined produces a tensor with four indices.

Comment: @Federico Poloni I don't understand what you are refering to by "operation OP". Is it the fact that you consider notation $\otimes$ ambiguous ?

Comment: OP = original poster. Let me paraphrase: the person who asked this question wanted an operation that produces rank-four tensors from matrices, not an operation that produces bigger matrices.

Comment: @Federico Poloni The original wording of the poster was different and did not insist that much on tensors. Moreover, if "implementation" is important for the asker, I don't see the point to avoid Kronecker products.